# Get td value on the click of button in asp.net which is bind with angualrJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a static HTML table in which have 2 column one is for employeeID and other is for Employee Name regarding every entry a asp:button appears generated. I want on the click of button it gives me employeeID.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <table border="1" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <th>Employee ID</th>
                    <th>Employee Name</th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="detail in details" align="center">
                    <td>{{ detail.EmployeeID }}</td>
                    <td>{{ detail.EmployeeName }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" Text="Delete Request" CommandArgument="{{detail.EmployeeID}}" runat="server" OnClick="btnDelete_Click"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Below is script to render value form XML in the table

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
            $http.get('myDB.xml')
            .then(function (response) {
                var x2js = new X2JS();
                //$scope.details = response.data.UserDetail;
                $scope.details = [];

                /*setting up the response*/
                var data = x2js.xml_str2json(response.data);
                $scope.details = data.UserDetail.Detail;
            });

        $scope.removerequest = function (row) {
            $scope.details.splice($scope.delete.indexOf(row), 1);
        }
    });
```

XMl

```
<UserDetail>
  <Detail>
    <EmployeeID>997857</EmployeeID>
    <EmployeeName>Aakash</EmployeeName>
  </Detail>
  <Detail>
    <EmployeeID>999786</EmployeeID>
    <EmployeeName>Amit</EmployeeName>
  </Detail>
</UserDetail>
```

Button click code

```
protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string id=btnApprove.CommandArgument;
    Response.Write(id);
    var xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\test\myDB.xml");
       xDoc.Descendants("Detail")
       .Elements("EmployeeID")
       .Where(x => x.Value == id)
       .Remove();
    xDoc.Save(@"D:\test\myDB.xml");
}
```

how to get td value in command argument form angularJS bind element

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the `employeeID` like so, `ng-click= btnDelete_Click( detail.EmployeeID )` in your button. this takes the scope variable defined by the ng-repeat and passes it as an argument for the function `BtnDelete_Click()`

Comment: could you please share the code which you have tried, cause I have tried this but can't get any output. After inspecting through developer options It is rendered  as "detail.EmployeeID" instead of it's value.

Comment: you have to place it within the ng-repeat